# Flex 4 how do compile an SWF so it does not require other SWF's and libs as seperate files

Tags: flex4, compilation, dependency-management

I want to include an flex 4 swf in a pdf to make it interactive, but I wish for it to compile it in such a way that any dependencies such as sparkskins_4.0.0.14159.swf and textlayout.swf etc.

Or at least that they are included rather into the swf.

I want a single SWF that can run on its own with everything it needs to function.

I'm sure there must be a way.

Please and thank you for any help you may provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure of new Flex 4/Flash builder, but in Flex Builder 3 you could go to project settings and ask to 'merge code' on all dependencies. That fixed this problem.

Comment: In the builder its to do with compiler options RSL versus merged in project settings, but giving you the tick :) thanks man :)